# add option value of the select box dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to populate the year in a select javascript. I did the following code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">         
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            var cur_year=new Date().getFullYear();
            var obj=document.getElementById("yr");  
            alert(obj);         
            for (var i = 2000; i <= 2020; i++)     {                
                opt = document.createElement("option");
                opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
                opt.selected = selected;
                opt.value = i;
                opt.text=i;
                obj.appendChild(opt);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="yr">
<option>year</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what is wrong in this. I want to populate the year and want to select the current year in the select box when the user opens the browser. Any one can help? please!

Comment: where is that value variable ?

Comment: if i delete that line- opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value()), what will happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
            var cur_year=new Date().getFullYear();
            var obj=document.getElementById("yr");         
            for (var i = 2000; i <= 2020; i++)     {                
                opt = document.createElement("option");
                opt.value = i;
                opt.text=i;
                obj.appendChild(opt);
            }
            document.getElementById("yr").value = cur_year;
        });
```

1. Just Use `.value` and assign `cur_year` to it.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5pYkW/)

Comment: Can you please tell the same code, without using the jquery. want to use javascript only.

Comment: @ijarlax see my updated answer it is just without IF statement.

Comment: @AspiringAqib : This is a place for giving people solution and getting solutions from others. Not a place for fighting like kids. I appreciate your answer, but if you don't learn to respect others and accept that someone else can also have the solution without your help, you cant get much progress..

Comment: @ijarlax : You can use `$("#yr")` in place of `document.getElementById("yr")`

Comment: @Avishek he wants pure JS as he commented above and ijarlax how it is possible? IE atleast supports `document.getElementById`

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
$current_year = date('Y');
$end_year = date('Y', strtotime('+10 years'));
?>
<label>Year</label><select name="year">
    <?php
for($i=$current_year; $i<=$end_year; $i++)
{
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: You should explain, what you did there.