# Write values in tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, tags, appendchild

I have this code

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var thirdElement = document.createElement("select");
        var thirdElementOp1 = document.createElement("option");
        thirdElementOp1.value = "--IDEAS--";
        var thirdElementOp2 = document.createElement("option");
        thirdElementOp2.value = "Random";
        var thirdElementOp3 = document.createElement("option");
        thirdElementOp3.value = "--FUN--";
        var thirdElementOp4 = document.createElement("option");
        thirdElementOp4.value = "Reflective";
        thirdElement.appendChild(thirdElementOp1);
        thirdElement.appendChild(thirdElementOp2);
        thirdElement.appendChild(thirdElementOp3);
        thirdElement.appendChild(thirdElementOp4);
        form.appendChild(thirdElement);
```

This appends all of these children into a form, generating the following HTML code:

```
<form id="form" action="home.php" method="post"> 
    <select>
        <option value="TheJSGeneratedValue"></option>
        <option value="TheJSGeneratedValue"></option>
        <option value="TheJSGeneratedValue"></option>
        <option value="TheJSGeneratedValue"></option>
    </select>
</form>
```

My problem is that for these values to appear on the dropdown menu, I have to write INSIDE the tag like so:

```
<option value="TheJSGeneratedValue">TheJSGeneratedValue</option>
```

Is there any way I can do this on JavaScript? I accept jQuery answers but I would appreciate a JavaScript one, I'm guessing it's something to do with `thirdElementOp1.valueInside = "Value"` or something like that maybe...

Comment: Will this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14827245/3264286

Answer (score 2):

The display text is separate from the value.  You set the display text with the `.innerHTML` property.

```
thirdElementOp1.value = "--IDEAS--";
thirdElementOp1.innerHTML = "--IDEAS--";
```

The `.value` property is what programmatic value the select will have if that particular option is selected or what value will be sent to a server if the form is submitted and that option is the selected one.  The `.value` is separate from the display value - though you can make them the same if you want by simply setting both properties to the same value.

---

FYI, your code is probably more compact if you just use an array of values and build the option objects from the array.  This avoids a lot of copied code and is a lot more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var select = document.createElement("select"), option;
var items = ["--IDEAS--", "Random", "--FUN--", "Reflective"];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = option.innerHTML = items[i];
    select.appendChild(option);
}
form.appendChild(select);
```

Comment: This worked, sorry, it was such a beginners question, I just forgot this part of the JavaScript tutorials, I'm a server-side guy so i know little of this, thanks, I will approve the answer once StackOverflow lets me!